# Iterating through directory for all csv files and creating kml for each individual(csv) file and save using file name

Tags: python, pandas, glob, simplekml

```
import csv
import simplekml
import pandas as pd
import glob

frame = pd.DataFrame()
filelist=glob.glob('/Users/germanportes/Documents/Status_Report/Telework_training/Anomaly_6/files/*.csv')
kml = simplekml.Kml()
for file in filelist:
    a6 =pd.read_csv(file)
    for row in a6:
        kml.newpoint(name=a6['idfa'], description = a6['device_os'],coords = [(a6['longitude'], a6['latitude'])])
kml.save('/Users/germanportes/Documents/Status_Report/Telework_training/Anomaly_6/files/kml/'+str(a6)+'.csv')
```

i like to save each individual csv as its own kml using the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're iterating over the columns instead of the rows and then you pass `pandas.Series` as columns to `kml.newpoint` arguments instead of some values. Use [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to iterate over the dataframe rows and add a point per each row to your kml object as follows:

```
from os.path import join
from glob import iglob
from pathlib import Path

import simplekml
import pandas as pd

csv_dir = 'path/to/csv/directory'
kml_dir = 'path/to/kml/directory'

for file in iglob(join(csv_dir, '*.csv')):
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # make an empty kml object
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    # iterate over the rows and and add new points to kml
    df.apply(lambda x: kml.newpoint(name=x['idfa'], description = x['device_os'], coords=[(x['longitude'], x['latitude'])]), axis=1)
    # save it as kml with the csv filename
    kml.save(join(kml_dir, '{}.kml'.format(Path(file).stem)))
```